# How to Open document.location.replace('//mydomain.com/sdfs?id='+myvar) URL in new tab?

Tags: javascript

i am new in javascript. i am facing one issue while running this js code. when i run this js code at time this code run in same tab, but i want to open in new tab. Here anyone know how to open in new tab or window??

**Javascript Code :-**

```html
//This code run in same tab, but i want to open in new tab or window.
<script>
document.location.replace('//mydomain.com/sdfs?id='+myvar);
</script>
```

- Basically when i run this javascript code at time this code open mydomain.com in same tab, but i want to open in new tab, so anyone have solution for that???

Comment: Should be easy to find with  _"javascript open url in new tab"_ -> `window.open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the target as `_blank` option to achieve this

try this code

`window.open('//mydomain.com/sdfs?id='+myvar, '_blank');`

Comment: For this OP would have to use `window.open()` - what is clearly not the case right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open URL in new tab you have to use `window.open`

```
window.open('//mydomain.com/sdfs?id='+myvar, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

use window.open() to open in new tab

**try this code**

```
window.open('//mydomain.com/sdfs?id='+myvar, '_blank');
```